# Not able to login into GCE instance via SSH while gcloud compute works perfectly

Tags: google-compute-engine

In one of my Google Compute engine instance, I am able to login using the gcloud command:
*gcloud compute --project "My-Project" ssh --zone "zone-name" "instance-name"*

But I am not able to ssh into it using the *ssh* button on browser or from command prompt. Below is the *serial version output*

> Sep  7 02:00:35 my-gce-instance sshd[25823]: Invalid user admin from 291.107.144.97
>
> Sep  7 02:00:35 my-gce-instance sshd[25823]: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 02:00:37 my-gce-instance sshd[25823]: Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures for admin [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 02:13:46 my-gce-instance sshd[26019]: Invalid user admin from 198.180.78.102
>
> Sep  7 02:13:46 my-gce-instance sshd[26019]: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 02:13:48 my-gce-instance sshd[26019]: Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures for admin [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 02:40:21 my-gce-instance sshd[26426]: Accepted publickey for gsc from 184.145.49.97 port 56371 ssh2: RSA c6:71:77:6d:56:e2:fb:b9:90:7d:df:bb:76:51:12:9a
>
> Sep  7 02:40:21 my-gce-instance sshd[26428]: Received disconnect from 184.145.49.97: 11: disconnected by user
>
> Sep  7 02:47:00 my-gce-instance sshd[26521]: Invalid user xml2epay from 193.107.155.192
>
> Sep  7 02:47:00 my-gce-instance sshd[26521]: input_userauth_request: invalid user xml2epay [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 02:47:01 my-gce-instance sshd[26521]: Connection closed by 193.107.155.192 [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 02:49:54 my-gce-instance sshd[26567]: Connection closed by 96.58.125.162 [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 02:56:36 my-gce-instance sshd[26673]: Accepted publickey for xxxx from 45.174.197.98 port 57017 ssh2: RSA 89:3a:9c:6e:2a:e3:bb:83:bb:da:4b:ac:c9:b5:c8:64
>
> Sep  7 03:01:21 my-gce-instance sshd[26769]: Invalid user admin from 92.100.179.159
>
> Sep  7 03:01:21 my-gce-instance sshd[26769]: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 03:01:22 my-gce-instance sshd[26770]: Invalid user admin from 92.100.179.159
>
> Sep  7 03:01:22 my-gce-instance sshd[26770]: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 03:01:25 my-gce-instance sshd[26769]: Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures for admin [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 03:01:27 my-gce-instance sshd[26770]: Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures for admin [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 03:01:37 my-gce-instance sshd[26773]: Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures for root [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 03:01:46 my-gce-instance sshd[26775]: Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures for root [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 03:01:51 my-gce-instance sshd[26777]: Invalid user usuario from 92.100.179.159
>
> Sep  7 03:01:51 my-gce-instance sshd[26777]: input_userauth_request: invalid user usuario [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 03:02:01 my-gce-instance sshd[26777]: Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures for usuario [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 03:04:35 my-gce-instance sshd[26838]: Connection closed by 78.195.41.87 [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 03:04:38 my-gce-instance sshd[26840]: Connection closed by 143.188.93.184 [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 03:04:42 my-gce-instance sshd[26842]: Connection closed by 143.188.93.180 [preauth]
>
> Sep  7 03:04:45 my-gce-instance sshd[26844]: Connection closed by 143.188.93.98 [preauth]

Comment: Can you post the output of the `gcloud compute disks describe DISK_NAME | grep sourceImage:` command? Replace `DISK_NAME` with the name of root disk of your VM.

Comment: @Kamran Sorry for late reply. Please find the disk name below:

**sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/backports-debian-7-wheezy-v20150818**

Comment: I'm looking into this issue and will try to post a solution on Friday.

Comment: Your VM instance was created from an old and deprecated Debian wheezy image and it's running an old version of the Google Accounts Daemon which is incompatible with new SSH metadata attributes. I'm still looking into this and will post a solution here soon.

Answer (score 0):

- Take a snapshot for backup purposes in case something goes wrong
  you can recover your VM instance.
- SSH into the VM instance via `gcloud` command.
- Run the command below to remove the older version of GCE daemons:

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove gce-daemon gce-startup-scripts gce-cloud-config**
  ```
- Then run this command to install the new GCE daemons:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall gce-compute-image-packages python-google-compute-engine**
  ```
- Reboot the instance, and try to SSH via Web browser.

Comment: Thanks @Kamran , I will try this today and let you know about the result.